# Laravel X Vuejs X Vuex loading concept

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code:

```
//Start Loading

load_post(id) {
    this.$store.dispatch('start_sub_loader');

    this.$router.push({ path: '/post/'+ this.hashid(id)});
},

//End Loading
mounted() {
    axios.get('/blah/blah/blah/' + this.$route.params.id).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);

        this.$store.commit("is_sub_loading_end");
        // or
        this.$store.dispatch('end_sub_loader');
    });
}
```

The problem is when I click a title it starts loading and the url change but it won't load the component, I've put a log there to check but it doesn't return a thing

Comment: Do you mean that `load_post` function is not running? If so, where do you call it?

Comment: No it works, but when I run it, it change the state and url, but it won't load the component

Comment: Are you expecting page data to update when `post/x` changes to `post/y` in the address bar?